# Customize RDoc::ClassModule#description

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I'm attempting to write a new generator for RDoc but I cannot figure out how to customize the `description` output for an `RDoc::ClassModule` object. Currently it looks like this:

```
<p><a href=\"Gist\">Gist</a> API is... lacking at the moment.</p>
```

I want to customize the link for "Gist" to be something different, such as `#!/search/Octopi::Gist` instead of just `Gist`.

How can I go about doing this?